# How to change view when form control value changes?

Tags: angular, angular-router, form-control

I have a component which is a search input with `[formControl]` property, i need to change the view when the user starts typing a search. I tried to do this by routing the user to a "search-view" component when the typing starts, however when the new view is rendered the search input gets cleaned. I need the user to be able to continue typing where he left after the "search-view" is rendered.

SearchComponent.html

`<input class="search-grid" type="search" [formControl]="searchControl">`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
@Component({
    selector: 'app-search',
    templateUrl: './search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
    private searchControl: FormControl;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.searchControl = new FormControl('');
        this.searchControl.valueChanges
            .subscribe(query => {                
            this.router.navigate(['/store-search']);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to rerender the whole page? Could you use a secondary `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Comment: Or instead of routing, using a child component? It may be easier to communicate changes to the child component as the user continues to type.

Comment: @DeborahK i understand what you say but how do i render the search view when the user starts typing?. I can see here [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) that the parent components renders child component in its template. In my case the search input component renders the input, and the search view component has its template too.

Comment: If you could build a little stackblitz of what you are trying to achieve and post the link to the editor here, I can show you how to use a child component.